# Shared Preference after service gets destroyed

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I have a query. In the service, Shared preference stores the value. If the service get destroyed/Killed, will the values too get destroyed. I am trying by creating an example and explicitly calling finish() which further calls destroy(). After reopening my app again. I am able to retrieve back the value which i stored earlier. Is this correct?

Comment: no value doesn't get destoryed it commit unless you clear data for your application

Comment: Yes that's correct. SharedPreference value are persisted untill you uninstall the app or clear data from the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you able to retrieve back the value but if you uninstall the app then the Shared preference stores the value are destroy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will not destroy unless and until you will not clear data from applications.

But make sure you have `commit` the data of `sharedPreferences`.

Yes you are able to fetch the values stored in `sharedPreferences` after opening the app again.

Answer (score 1):

No value doesn't get destoryed it commit unless you clear data for your application